# How to schedule replicas and persistent volume in different availability zones

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes

I have an AWS EKS cluster and I deployed the MongoDB replica set using operator version 0.9.0. The replica set deployment file I used is given below,

> ```
> apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
> kind: MongoDBCommunity
> metadata:
>   name: mongodb-test
>   namespace: mongodb-test
> spec:
>   members: 3
>   type: ReplicaSet
>   version: "7.0.0"
>   security:
>     authentication:
>       modes: ["SCRAM"]
>   users:
>     - name: mongouser
>       db: admin
>       passwordSecretRef: # a reference to the secret that will be used to generate the user's password
>         name: password
>       roles:
>         - name: clusterAdmin
>           db: admin
>         - name: userAdminAnyDatabase
>           db: admin
>       scramCredentialsSecretName: mongodb-scram
>   statefulSet:
>     spec:
>       template:
>         spec:
>           nodeSelector:
>             server: mongo
>           # resources can be specified by applying an override
>           # per container name.
>           containers:
>             - name: mongod
>               resources:
>                 limits:
>                   cpu: "0.3"
>                   memory: 700M
>                 requests:
>                   cpu: "0.2"
>                   memory: 500M
>             - name: mongodb-agent
>               resources:
>                 limits:
>                   cpu: "0.2"
>                   memory: 500M
>                 requests:
>                   cpu: "0.1"
>                   memory: 250M
>       volumeClaimTemplates:
>         - metadata:
>             name: data-volume
>           spec:
>             resources:
>               storageClassName: sc1
>               requests:
>                 storage: 10Gi
>         - metadata:
>             name: logs-volume
>           spec:
>             storageClassName: sc1
>             resources:
>               requests:
>                 storage: 2Gi
> ```

Below is the commands I used to deploy mongodb,

```
kubectl apply -f mongodb-kubernetes-operator/crd/mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com_mongodbcommunity.yaml

kubectl get crd/mongodbcommunity.mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com

kubectl apply -k mongodb-kubernetes-operator/rbac/ --namespace mongodb-test

kubectl create -f mongodb-kubernetes-operator/manager/manager.yaml --namespace mongodb-test

kubectl apply -f replicaset/rbac -n mongodb-test

kubectl apply -f replicaset/replica-set.yaml -n mongodb-test
```

Is there any way I can,

> 1. Schedule MongoDB replicas in different availability zones.
> 2. Schedule the replica in the same availability zone as the replica's persistent volume.

```
        eg: replica1, replica1's persistent volume in eu-west-1a
            replica2, replica2's persistent volume in eu-west-1b
            replica, replica3's persistent volume in eu-west-1c
```

Operator Version: v0.9.0

MongoDB Image used: quay.io/mongodb/mongodb-community-server:7.0.0-ubi8

Kubernetes Cluster Version: v1.26.11-eks-8cb36c9

Comment: What do you mean by "Schedule MongoDB replicas"? What you could do is a [Delayed Replica Set Member](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/). Or you may configure the [Secondary's Sync Target](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-secondary-sync-target/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `StorageClass` has the `volumeBindingMode` set to `WaitForFirstConsumer`. This ensures the volumes won't be provisioned until the pod is scheduled on the appropriate node.

**Disclaimer**: I have not used `topologySpreadConstraints` before but this *should* work.

```yaml
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: mongodb-test
  namespace: mongodb-test
spec:
  members: 3
  type: ReplicaSet
  version: "7.0.0"
  security:
    authentication:
      modes: ["SCRAM"]
  users:
    - name: mongouser
      db: admin
      passwordSecretRef: # a reference to the secret that will be used to generate the user's password
        name: password
      roles:
        - name: clusterAdmin
          db: admin
        - name: userAdminAnyDatabase
          db: admin
      scramCredentialsSecretName: mongodb-scram
  statefulSet:
    spec:
      template:
        # Add a label to identify the pods for spread constraint
        metadata:
          labels:
            app.kubernetes.io/part-of: mongodb
        spec:
          # Add a topologySpreadConstraint to spread the pods across AZs
          topologySpreadConstraints:
          - maxSkew: 1
            topologyKey: topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone
            labelSelector:
              matchLabels:
                app.kubernetes.io/part-of: mongodb
          nodeSelector:
            server: mongo
          # resources can be specified by applying an override
          # per container name.
          containers:
            - name: mongod
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: "0.3"
                  memory: 700M
                requests:
                  cpu: "0.2"
                  memory: 500M
            - name: mongodb-agent
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: "0.2"
                  memory: 500M
                requests:
                  cpu: "0.1"
                  memory: 250M
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: data-volume
          spec:
            resources:
              storageClassName: sc1
              requests:
                storage: 10Gi
        - metadata:
            name: logs-volume
          spec:
            storageClassName: sc1
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 2Gi
```

Comment: But after a POD restart, The POD schedules on az1 but its persistent volume is in az2. Then it can cause a volume node affinity error. How can we tackle that ?

Comment: @SebinnSebastian that is done with the `volumeBindingMode` on the `StorageClass`. You can't edit that parameter on an existing storage class so if anything else is using the `sc1` storage class you'll need to create a new one with `volumeBindingMode` set to `WaitForFirstConsumer` and update your `volumeClaimTemplates`.

Comment: If a pod is descheduled, deleted and recreated, or an instance where the pod was running is terminated then WaitForFirstConsumer won’t help because it only applies to the first pod that consumes a volume. When a pod reuses an existing EBS volume there is still a chance that the pod will be scheduled in an AZ where the EBS volume doesn’t exist.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-eks-cluster-multi-zone-auto-scaling-groups/